# OP replicated my answer with a different account and then accepted it

Tags: discussion

OP asked how to center a `div` horizontally using Bootstrap, I provided an answer. Next thing I know, he comments saying: "Thanks for helping. But it does not work. I have solved it. Solution is given in my answer". Since I wanted know what was wrong with my answer, I went on to see 'his' answer. To my surprise it was a replica of my answer posted by a just-created username and accepted by the OP.

Is this a valid use of StackOverflow?

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186037/twitter-bootstrep-3-make-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically-centered/28186209#28186209)

Comment: It's not identical, the OP uses row-fluid not row. Though you've obviously influenced the OPs answer somewhat it takes the teeth from your accusation. We prefer to have all the information in one answer, so having 1 correct is good, would prefer a lot not information though.

Comment: He said my solution didn't work. In what way using `row` instead of `row-fluid` makes my original solution not work, then?

Comment: The accepted answer was posted by an account that is older than the OP's account. Still, I have flagged the post for moderator attention, because using a second account to post an answer then accept it is considered voting fraud; I'll leave it to the moderators to sort that one out.

Comment: Haven't used bootstrap 3 in a while, but from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9897227/2958086) I see no reason why your answer would not work versus his, and in fact, it recommends being consistent with container/row and container-fluid/row-fluid. I don't feel like changing that one term would have any effect on the actual output from my interpretation. Someone with more bootstrap experience might be able to validate this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a different account to post an answer that can then be accepted is not allowed, as both accounts benefit from the acceptance in a way that accepting a self-answer does not. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

In this particular case, the account does indeed belong to the same user, but it's not clear-cut whether the user means to cheat the system. After all, he claims ownership of that answer in his comment that you quoted. Perhaps he's just not aware that he can self-answer and so thought he had to create a separate account in order to do so.

Regardless, what the user is doing is not allowed, so I will remove the answer (as we can't transfer ownership of answers) and notify the user.

Comment: Can't you merge accounts?

Comment: @Tim Seguine: Not anymore :( I could ask the staff to do so, but I figured that would be too much trouble for just one answer. Plus, teach a user to fish, etc.